# How to find x rows above and below a criteria match in pandas data-frame and then save them as a new df?

Tags: python, pandas

I have currently got a pandas dataframe that works out the %change using df.column.pct_change() and I want filter all rows that have a change greater than 30%. I can already do this. Then using the output I want to take the row above the row with a % change greater than 30 then take the next 6 rows below and somehow if the %change is within the last 6 rows of the data ignore that so I don't get an error of wanting to use data that doesn't exist.

DATE.....  OPEN.....    CLOSE.....    PERCENTCHANGE.....

XXX........     xxx...........     xxx...........             xxx.....
XXX........     xxx...........     xxx...........             xxx.....
AAA........     xxx...........     xxx...........             xxx.....
BBB........     xxx...........     31%...........             xxx.....
CCC........     xxx...........     xxx...........             xxx.....
DDD........     xxx...........     xxx...........             xxx.....
EEE........     xxx...........     xxx...........             xxx.....
FFF........     xxx...........     xxx...........             xxx.....
GGG........     xxx...........     xxx...........             xxx.....
HHH........     xxx...........     xxx...........             xxx.....
If thats my table and the line BBB has a 31% change I want the program to save rows AAA all the way through to HHH as a new dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_upper = df.loc[df.PERCENTCHANGE <= 30]
df_lower = df.loc[df.PERCENTCHANGE > 30]


df_required = pd.concat([df_upper.tail(1), df_lower])
```

Thanks, Anshul